# Can 'case - when' returns mutiple results?

Tags: sql, hive

Assume there is a table dim_user_info which comprises non-repeat `user_id` and its `id_number`.
Now I want to classify them:

```
select
a.user_id,
(case when user_id in (1,3,5,7) then 'class1'
when id_number in (128,329,349) then 'vip'
end) as category
from dim_user_info a
```

If a piece of user info meets two conditions at the same time, I want to get the full info, like `user c` in the following table:

```
user_id  id_number   category
1          111        class1
2          128         vip
3          329        class1
3          329         vip
6          128         vip
7           55        class1
```

Is this doable in hive? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `user_id` can be either `1,3,5 or 7` or `'a','c' or 'e'`, not both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a `UNION` query:

```
select
    user_id,
    'class1' as category
from dim_user_info
where user_id in (1,3,5,7)
union all
select
    user_id,
    'vip'
from dim_user_info
where id_number in (128,329,349)
```

I don't know if this would be the most performant solution in Hive SQL, but it is one way to have the same record appear multiple times, once for each possible matching category.

If you also want to include non matching users, you could use another union for that.

Comment: non classfied users, i.E. user-iid 4(with non-matching id_number)  won't be listed here, and you took twice user_id instead of id_number in the second query

Comment: I dont' think so, look at his `id_number in (128,329,349)` and your where clause

Comment: Ow, you deleted your comment, now everone thinks I'm talking to myself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If not all users are classified, you could use a classification table with the columns

user_id,
id_number,
category

and the query

```
select
a.user_id, c.category
from dim_user_info a
left outer join  classification c 
on (a.user_id = c.user_id or a.id_number = c.id_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  ui.usr
       ,e.col

from    dim_user_info ui
        lateral view explode(array(
             case when user_id   in (1,3,5,7)     then 'class1' end
            ,case when id_number in (128,329,349) then 'vip'    end
            )) e

where   e.col is not null
```